# How to get undecoded filename

Tags: java, c++, c

Could somebody please give me some tips about how to get undecoded byte[] of filename?
I want to do the decoding myself.
I have traced java src code, but I am blocked by native function.
Thanks a lot!

I mean I want the original byte[] of filename, not convert it to a string and then convert it back. This may cause some filename using native encoding but not unicode to lose its original bytes. JAVA always give me the filename decoded by unicode and I do not want it.

I am assuming I have to handle some files from somewhere, and I do not exactly know the encoding they use. However, I just do not want the system to do decoding for me. I want to decide myself which kind of decoding should be used. So I need the original byte[] of filename.

Solution in C/C++ is also appreciated.

Comment: Define "undecoded". There ain't no such thing as plain text.

Comment: You need to use the same encoding as your OS. In Java that should be the default encoding. If you use that you should get the filename/paths as the OS sees them.

Comment: I think you want the actual 8 bit byte values as they come off the hard drive, trivial in c or c++ but the Java team I work with failed to find a reliable method in Java

Comment: You're right David. If you know how to do this in C/C++, could you please tell me?

Comment: @oldfat: Mistaken assumption there. Java is portable and has to work on Windows, where filenames are generally 16 bits unicode (UTF-16) codepoints (on both VFAT and NTFS). So you can't even say that there _is_ an "undecoded" file name, let alone a `byte[]`

Comment: You have point it put MSalters, but I still have a question. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS tells that the file system does not check whether a sequence is valid UTF-16 (it allows any sequence of short values, not restricted to those in the Unicode standard). I do not really understand it, could you please interpret it?

Comment: @oldfat: I don't know about this part of the NTFS spec, but it probably just means that Windows will accept any sequence of bytes/shorts as a filename. Not all such sequences are valid UTF-16 sequences, but Windows will not check that before creating a file. So a file name on disk could be a byte sequence that can not be interpreted as UTF-16. In that case it would indeed be interesting to get the "real" native byte sequence, but I don't think Java allows this, unless you use JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made the comment that in c/c++ it is trivial I meant that in my experience c and c++ rarely converts data without being told to, and you should get what you want by doing nothing.

To get the file name I'd expect you to have to iterater the contents of the folder.
Two methods of doing this are to call FindFirstFile(), followed by FindNextFile

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE findFile;
findFile = FindFirstFile (path, &findData);
FindNextFile (findFile, &findData);
```

or

```
wpath ourPath(pDirectory);
wdirectory_iterator endIter;
for (wdirectory_iterator iter(ourPath); iter != endIter; ++iter)
{
 pContents.push_back(iter->leaf());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the standard Java API does not offer any way to retrieve the byte stream that the underlying OS uses as the "native" filename; all the APIs handle filenames as `java.lang.String`s, hence in Unicode.

You can of course convert a `String` back to a `byte[]` using String.getBytes, but that will not give you the original representation. I guess the only way to get that is to use JNI and the OS-native filesystem API.

In practice, on Windows that would mean that you take your C/C++ code to get the file name, and invoke it via JNI to get the "real" filename.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you really want to achieve. Usually, if we work with files, we do not *get* filenames but *provide* filenames to access files. A *filename* is a sequence of bytes which can be converted to a *String* following a given encoding.

To create a String in special encoding, use:

```
byte[] filenameBytes = getBytesFromWhereEver();
String filename = new String(filenameBytes, "UTF-8");
```

the example will encode the bytes to an UTF-8 String. But still you'll have to *provide* the filename or at least, it's bytes.